# Instead of FAQ why isn't it called README?

Tags: discussion

"First time here? Check out the FAQ!" Really, Frequently Asked Questions? It seems to be a misnomer in these cases. README.txt seems to a a truer and more playful term for these Frequently Tell To Read documents on the trinity.

Answer (score 4):

I guess it depends if "FAQ" has made the leap from internet terminology to greater mainstream awareness.

I suppose it could be called "new user guide" or "getting started" or something like that, but /faq does have a nice brevity to it.

Answer (score 1):

Of course "frequently asked questions" aren't *frequently asked* because everyone knows they are in the FAQ.

It's a [self-defeating prophecy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-defeating_prophecy): Pre-answering the questions prevents them from being asked in the first place. But nobody want to call it the PAQYDHTA.

Comment: Okay, I do. Please make this a feature-request to change FAQ to PAQYDHTA.

Answer (score 0):

This is a QUESTION site, not a README site.

Comment: But the QUESTIONS aren't actually FREQUENTLY ASKED

Comment: @Kinopiko: Some are, some *really* are...